# CSS ellipsis not working when width is set to a percentage

Tags: html, css

I have the following DOM structure:

[**JSFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/25vu1ae9/)

```
    <table class="tbl">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            A lot of text in hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            A lot of text in hereeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>

    table.tbl{
        background-color: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-collapse: separate;
        border-radius: 5px;
        float: left;
        margin: 10px 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

    table.tbl tr {
        font-weight: 400;
        text-align: left;
    }

    table.tbl th {
        color: #FFF;
        font-weight: 400;
        padding: 6px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    table.tbl td {
        padding: 10px 8px;
    }

    table.tbl div {
        max-width: 100%;
        display: inline-flex;
    }

    table.tbl span {
        width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
```

This table is located on the right hand side of my page, but if there is a large amount of text in one or both of the span tags, the table extends extends off my page.

I have to keep the table at `width: 100%` as it needs to fill all available space on the right hand side of my page.

Can I add a CSS ellipsis to the span tag but keep the overall width of the table at `width: 100%`?

It doesn't seem to be working for me at the moment, any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Need something like this [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/25vu1ae9/1) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try his one:

```
table.tbl{
            background-color: #FFF;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            border-collapse: separate;
            border-radius: 5px;
            float: left;
            margin: 10px 0;
            width: 100%; 
            table-layout: fixed;
        }

        table.tbl tr {
            font-weight: 400;
            text-align: left;
        }

        table.tbl th {
            color: #FFF;
            font-weight: 400;
            padding: 6px;
            text-align: left;
        }

        table.tbl td {
            padding: 10px 8px;
        }

        table.tbl div {
            max-width: 100%;
            display: inline-flex;
        }

        table.tbl span {
            width: 100%;
            white-space: nowrap;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/25vu1ae9/5/)

Comment: `table-layout: fixed;`... brilliant!